# TcpClient does not read response from the server (.Net core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, network-programming, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am currently working on a network project that needs to send a request to the server and gets a response from it. The server is hosted by the third party company so I don't have direct access to the server but I can request server logs. According to that logs, my request was successfully sent to the server and the server also replies with the response. But the response doesn't receive to my side. I also used Packet Sender Tool to check the response and it also didn't receive any response. What could be the issue here? There is nothing wrong with my code because I receive responses when I connect to different servers. this problem only occurs with one specific server. Thanks all.

//establish TcpConnection

```
public async Task<TcpClient> ConnectAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
  {
     string xmlMessageServer = _configuration["XmlMessageStrings:xmlMessageServer"];
     string xmlMessagePort = _configuration["XmlMessageStrings:xmlMessagePort"];

     var errorLog = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config").GetLogger("debitcardErrorLog");

     try
     {
        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(xmlMessageServer, Convert.ToInt32(xmlMessagePort));
        errorLog.Info(tcpClient.GetHashCode());
        return tcpClient;
     }
     catch (SocketException ex)
     {
        errorLog.Error(ex.Message); // log error
        throw ex;
     }
  }
```

---

```
  try
     {
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        await _connectWithTcpServer.ConnectAsync(tcpClient);

        if (tcpClient.Connected)
        {
           debitcardRequestLog.Info("Tcp Client Connected"); // check if client connected

           NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

           debitcardRequestLog.Info(xmlMessage); // log xmlMessage

           byte[] xmlRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlMessage); // converts the xmlRequest into a byte array
           stream.Write(xmlRequest, 0, xmlRequest.Length); //writes the xmlRequest into the stream

           byte[] bufferSize = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize]; //converts the bufferSize into a byte array

           int xmlResponse =  stream.Read(bufferSize, 0, bufferSize.Length);  //reads the xml response from switchware

           if (xmlResponse == 0)
           {
              errorLog.Error("0 bytes received from server");
           }

           string xmlResponseMsg = string.Empty;
           string xmlResponseMsgASCII = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferSize, 0, 0); // decode the byte array into a string

           debitcardResponseLog.Info(xmlResponseMsgASCII);

           fromSwitchwareMessage = xmlResponseMsgASCII;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        errorLog.Error(ex.Message); // log error
        throw ex;
     }
```

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferSize, 0, 0);` Count == 0 ?

Comment: "`int xmlResponse =  stream.Read(bufferSize, 0, bufferSize.Length);  //reads the xml response from switchware`" - important point: no it doesn't; it reads *at least one byte* (or failure); TCP is a *streaming* protocol - you are **not** guaranteed to get the same payload layout in terms of how the other end sent them, or receive entire frames - you need to add your own framing protocol if you're going to be receiving multiple messages on the same pipe; if you're dealing with things like UTF8, that includes receiving partial characters (different byte portions in different `Read` operations)

Comment: Sorry my bad it's string xmlResponseMsgASCII = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferSize, 0, bufferSize.Length); but still dosen't get a resposne.

Comment: @BuddhikaNelum what is the value of `xmlResponse`? when you say "still doesn't get a resposne" - what exactly *does* happen? does it just block forever at `Read`? or do you get something? if so, what? note: you should only even look at bytes `[0,xmlResponse)`, so that should be at best `GetString(bufferSize, 0, xmlResponse)` (and those are some *terribly* confusing names for the locals! `bufferSize` isn't a size, and `xmlResponse` isn't xml!)

Comment: @MarcGravell No it doesn't block at read but it takes some time like 2-3 minutes. the server logs proves that they got my request successfully and they send the response. The thing is when reading the response I always get 0 for xmlResponse.

Comment: If you get `0` from `Read`, then **the connection ended**, presumably via a timeout+disconnect. Are you absolutely sure they sent something? Did the sender flush their outbound buffers? Are they perhaps waiting on a handshake from you before they send something?

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't even receive a response for a handshake request. according to there logs, they send the response,

Comment: @BuddhikaNelum don't trust their logs; just connect with telnet or similar: do you get anything?

Comment: @MarcGravell telnet works fine. I don't understand what went wrong. it could be a time out like you said. I need to figure it out soon :(